# Integrate Galleriffic with Lightbox, how?

Tags: jquery, image, lightbox

Anybody has a idea how to intergrate Lightbox 0.5 with Galleriffic? (http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/)

When you click on the download button/text I want the image to open in a lightbox.

Greatings,
Bas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish this, you will need to call the lightbox function each time an image/caption is loaded.  You would need to do this in the galleriffic onTransitionIn callback like such:

```
...
onTransitionIn:         function() {
    $('#slideshow').fadeIn('fast');
    $('#caption').fadeIn('fast', function() {
        $('#caption a.lightbox').lightBox();
    });
},
...
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

It's a while since you posted this question so you may have already discovered this but .......

Matt Gifford who has actually designed a plug-in integrating galleriffic and lightbox!!! and called it gallerifficPlusjquery.  Pretty cool! hey just what you wanted.  You don't have to call up lightbox everytime with this version.

You can find it on his website at: [GallerifficPlus jquery Plug-in](http://www.mattgifford.co.uk/gallerificplus-jquery-plugin/)

Cheers
kara

Answer (score 1):

```
onTransitionIn: function() {
    $('#slideshow').fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
    $('#slideshow span.image-wrapper').fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
    $('#caption').fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
    $('#caption span.image-caption').fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
    $('#caption').fadeIn('fast', function() {
        $('#caption a.lightbox').lightBox();
    });
},
```